# React Native con React Navigation error nanoid

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Tengo un problema al intentar instalar React Navigation, estoy siguiendo la documentación pero me salen unos errores. Estoy usando expo-cli.

Primero "npm install @react-navigation/native" y me sale esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for nanoid@3.1.9: wanted: {"node":"^10 || ^12 || >=13.7"} (current: {"node":"13.6.0","npm":"6.14.5"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: nanoid@3.1.9
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @react-navigation/native@5.5.0 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN expo-asset@8.1.5 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @unimodules/react-native-adapter@5.2.0 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN expo-linking@1.0.1 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN expo-font@8.1.1 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-view-shot@3.1.2 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Luego "expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view" y me da este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Installing 5 SDK 37.0.0 compatible native modules using Yarn.
> yarn add react-native-gesture-handler@~1.6.0 react-native-reanimated@~1.7.0 react-native-screens@~2.2.0 react-native-safe-area-context@0.7.3 @react-native-community/masked-view@0.1.6
yarn add v1.22.4
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error nanoid@3.1.9: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^10 || ^12 || >=13.7". Got "13.6.0"
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
error Found incompatible module.
yarnpkg exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: yarnpkg exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:65:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:428:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1028:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
    ...
    at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:26:19)
    at YarnPackageManager._runAsync (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\package-manager\src\NodePackageManagers.ts:279:31)
    at YarnPackageManager.addAsync (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\package-manager\src\NodePackageManagers.ts:236:16)
    at installAsync (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\install.ts:72:3)
    at Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\exp.ts:80:7)
```

Comment: Procura agregar el error como texto, no como imagen, para que sea más sencillo de leer y se te pueda ayudar. Gracias.

Comment: Tu versión de node.js está desactualizada. Intenta descargarte la última versión.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hice así y me funciona.

**LIBRERIA PARA NAVEGAR ENTRE PAGINAS:**

npm install @react-navigation/native

expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view

npm install @react-navigation/stack

**La primera línea de código debe ser:**

import 'react-native-gesture-handler'

Lo que veo es que te aparece npm y yarm. Yo usaría uno u otro, pero si usas los dos deben tener diferentes ficheros .lock

Saludos